# Pandas: Enforcing consistent values for inner index across all outer index values

Tags: pandas, multi-index, reindex

I have a dataset indexed by entity_id and timestamp, but certain entity_id's do not have entries at all timestamps (not missing values, just no row). I'm trying to enforce consistent timestamps across the entity_ids prior to some complicated NaN handling and resampling. But, I cannot get reindex to create the rows I was expecting, and it is leading to unexpected behavior downstream. My approach was:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["id", "ts", "value"])
df.loc[0,:] = [1, pd.Timestamp("2022-01-01 00:00:00"), 1]
df.loc[1,:] = [1, pd.Timestamp("2022-01-01 00:00:01"), 2]
df.loc[2,:] = [2, pd.Timestamp("2022-01-01 00:00:00"), 3]
df = df.set_index(["id", "ts"])
df

# Grab all the timestamps
timestamps = df.index.get_level_values("ts").unique().sort_values()

# Perform the reindexing
df2 = df.reindex(timestamps, level = 1, axis = 0, fill_value = np.nan)
```

However, this leaves my dataframe unchanged, i.e., df2 still only has 3 rows. Maybe reindexing isn't the right approach here, but I thought it would work.

Is there a best practice for this sort of operation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#added sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["id", "ts", "value"])
df.loc[0,:] = [1, pd.Timestamp("2022-01-01 00:00:00"), 1]
df.loc[1,:] = [1, pd.Timestamp("2022-01-01 00:00:01"), 2]
df.loc[2,:] = [2, pd.Timestamp("2022-01-01 00:00:00"), 3]
df.loc[3,:] = [3, pd.Timestamp("2022-01-01 00:00:04"), 4]
df = df.set_index(["id", "ts"])
print (df)
                       value
id ts                       
1  2022-01-01 00:00:00     1
   2022-01-01 00:00:01     2
2  2022-01-01 00:00:00     3
3  2022-01-01 00:00:04     4
```

If need add missing consecutive datetimes by [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with minimal and maximal values use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) with all `ids` and dates and pass to [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
dates = pd.date_range(df.index.levels[1].min(), df.index.levels[1].max(), freq='S')

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0], dates], names=df.index.names)

out1 = df.reindex(mux)
print (out1)
                       value
id ts                       
1  2022-01-01 00:00:00     1
   2022-01-01 00:00:01     2
   2022-01-01 00:00:02   NaN
   2022-01-01 00:00:03   NaN
   2022-01-01 00:00:04   NaN
2  2022-01-01 00:00:00     3
   2022-01-01 00:00:01   NaN
   2022-01-01 00:00:02   NaN
   2022-01-01 00:00:03   NaN
   2022-01-01 00:00:04   NaN
3  2022-01-01 00:00:00   NaN
   2022-01-01 00:00:01   NaN
   2022-01-01 00:00:02   NaN
   2022-01-01 00:00:03   NaN
   2022-01-01 00:00:04     4
```

If need [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by unique values of both levels of `MultiIndex`:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names=df.index.names)
out2 = df.reindex(mux)
print (out2)
                       value
id ts                       
1  2022-01-01 00:00:00     1
   2022-01-01 00:00:01     2
   2022-01-01 00:00:04   NaN
2  2022-01-01 00:00:00     3
   2022-01-01 00:00:01   NaN
   2022-01-01 00:00:04   NaN
3  2022-01-01 00:00:00   NaN
   2022-01-01 00:00:01   NaN
   2022-01-01 00:00:04     4
```

Comment: Thanks! I timed the two approaches listed here, and this one was the fastest on 30 minutes of 1 second frequency data (1.67 ms +/ 6.82 microseconds versus 275 ms +/- 4.46 ms). This answer also takes in the structure of the dataset correctly, and outputs it in the right format.

Answer (score 0):

I have this solution came into my mind to make use of `pd.pivot_table()` and `pd.melt()`.

Kindly find below for my code:

```
# Create the sample dataset
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["id", "ts", "value"])
df.loc[0,:] = [1, pd.Timestamp("2022-01-01 00:00:00"), 1]
df.loc[1,:] = [1, pd.Timestamp("2022-01-01 00:00:01"), 2]
df.loc[2,:] = [2, pd.Timestamp("2022-01-01 00:00:00"), 3]

# Pivot the dataset
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    values='value',
    index='id',
    columns='ts'
).reset_index()

# Melt the pivoted dataset
df_result = pd.melt(
    df_pivot,
    id_vars='id',
    value_vars=list(df_res.columns[1:]),
    var_name='ts', 
    value_name='value'
)
```

The result I got as below:

```
   id                  ts  value
0   1 2022-01-01 00:00:00    1.0
1   2 2022-01-01 00:00:00    3.0
2   1 2022-01-01 00:00:01    2.0
3   2 2022-01-01 00:00:01    NaN
```

You can fill the missing value by using `fill_value` param in `pd.pivot_table()` if you want, you may refer the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html).
Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This approach works with the correctly formatted data if we replace `df` with `df.reset_index` in the pivot table call, and `df_res` with `df_pivot` in the `melt` call. It is slightly slower than the accepted answer though, but definitely functional :)